# Redirect to new page in new tab after processing - Oracle Apex

Tags: oracle-apex, oracle-apex-19.2

On button click I call process (eg. update table) and then call below code to redirect on new page in new tab (jasper report).

After processing > Branches > Page or Url redirect

**javascript:window.open('fp= my_url_work_100% ,'_blank');**

Nothing happens! Any idea where is problem!

What is best solution for redirect to new page in new tab after processing?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what is *the best* solution, but - to me, it seems that target URL is **invalid**. What is it supposed to represent?

- `fp=` *looks like* beginning of Apex' URL, but - it begins with `f?p=` (note the question sign)

  - if you used it, then you'd navigate to **another page** in this application, but - why not using "Page in this application" target type, then?
- however, you said that you want to open report (result of what Jasper Report returns)
- if that's so, then URL should represent address of that report

  - I don't use Jasper Report, but - I do have Oracle Reports, and when calling such a report, address contains **reports server name** (the whole `http://reports_server_address/reports/rwservlet/...`). I'd expect that you should do the same

---

Maybe you should

- create target URL (as part of process you mentioned) and store it into **page item**
- then create branch which redirects to **URL identified by that item**

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible to execute javascript in a branch. The branch is evaluated at the server side and will then redirect to the url identified in the branch. The string "javascript:window.open('fp= my_url_work_100% ,'_blank');" is not a valid url, it is a client side javascript call to open an url in a new tab.

A possible solution is to redirect to the same page with a specific page item value - or a REQUEST value and have a dynamic action to fire on load that execute the javascript call.

Another solution is to not use page processing/branch but a dynamic action and do the redirect in another action after the one that does the pl/sql processing.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks all for help, my solution is bellow.

Use modal page (page 2 in this example)

1. When open modal page from page 1 I set **P_ITEM = 0**
2. I have two button on modal page

**BTN_PREPARE** (call process preprare print send data to databse and set **P_ITEM value = 1**)

**BTN_OPEN_JASPER** (open jasper from dynamic action =>

```
javascript:window.open('f?p=&APP_ID.:1:&APP_SESSION.::::XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX','_blank');
```

3. On page load I execute javascript code if **P_ITEM = 1**

**$("#BTN_OPEN_JASPER").click();**

4. In inline css:

**#BTN_OPEN_JASPER{ display: none;}**

5. When click on **BTN_PREPARE** submit page now **P_ITEM = 1** and **BTN_OPEN_JASPER** is fire and open in new tab report!

Note:

I don't know is above example good solution but work!